# TDataModule inheritance

Tags: delphi-2010, datamodule, delphi

When I'm trying to inherit TDataModule Delphi treat descendant class like a form giving them properties like font and Client properties. ("property does not exists" exception on a run-time)

```
TixDataModule = class(TDataModule);

TDM = class(TixDataModule)
end;
```

What Can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As TixDatamodule is just a synonym for TDatamodule, you can inherit directly from TDataModule
2. If you really want to inherit from TixDataModule, then put TixDataModule in a separate unit, with its own .dfm.

Comment: I just want to override the AfterConstruction method

Comment: @JustMe: In TixDatamodule, or in TDM? For just overriding a method, you don't need the TisDatamodule

Comment: @JustMe: I assume, you want to override in the TDM the AfterConstruction method of the TDatamodule. In this case you just create a datamodule, and put **procedure AfterConstruction; override** in the class interface...

Comment: @Toto I know that, but You see I want to override this procedure in all datamodules I have - so I think it would be good idea to add TixDataModule class and make all DataModules inherit from it

Comment: @JustMe: Ok, now it's clear to me. Then create the TixDatamodule, as a normal datamodule, overwrite whatever you want, and then create TDM by File|New|Other... and from the Inheritable Items group select TixDatamodule

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that all the inherited components is marked with `inherited` rather than `object` in the in the dfm.

Toggle "dfm as text" and "dfm as visual" with Alt+F12.

Comment: @JustMe: +1; this is indeed the cause of the "property does not exists" problem. See also my [TInterfacedDatamodule revisited](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/delphi-tinterfaceddatamodule-revisted-inherited-in-your-dfm-files-when-your-datamodules-look-like-forms-in-the-designer/) blog post for a more detailed example of what this answer explains. The article explains how to do DataModule inheritance, and how to correct datamodules that you now want to inherit from your `TixDataModule `.

Comment: @Jeroen You're right, when you inherit like Toto (answered) problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @JustMe indeed, for new DataModules to inherit from TixDataModule, it does not matter. It does matter for existing DataModules that you want to inherit from TixDataModule. Since usually developers are maintaining stuff 80% of the time, the latter is very important.